Stability in Dynamic Systems
I am really having a hard time figuring out the solution of this problem :
Consider a continuous flux on X. Let M ⊂ X be non-empty, compact, and invariant. Prove or disprove that M is stable if and only if each neighborhood of M contains a positive invariant neighborhood of M.
Thanks for help,
Proof
( $\Rightarrow$ ) Stability implies the neighborhood condition
Assume $M$ is stable. By definition of stability, for every neighborhood $U$ of $M$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $M$ such that:
$ \phi(t, V) \subseteq U \quad \text{for all} \; t \geq 0.$
We need to find a positively invariant neighborhood within (U). Since $\phi(t, V) \subseteq U$ $\forall (t \geq 0 $, it implies $V$ is mapped into $U$ under the flow for all positive times.
Define $(W = \bigcup_{t \geq 0} \phi(t, V)$. $W$ is a neighborhood of $M$ because $V$ is a neighborhood of $M$ and the union of its images under the continuous flow $\phi$ remains a neighborhood of $M$. Furthermore, $W$ is positively invariant by construction, as:
$ \phi(s, W) = \phi(s, \bigcup_{t \geq 0} \phi(t, V)) = \bigcup_{t \geq 0} \phi(s+t, V) = W. $
Hence, $W \subseteq U$ and $W$ is positively invariant.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Please correct your mathjax errors; your post is currently almost unreadable.

Beyond that, it's rather unclear what your question is. Your post starts with the assertion that you are having a hard time, and then continues with a detailed proof. What do you wish to ask?

Sir Mosher, Thank you for your answer and sorry for the incovenience : i had a hard time with mathjax. The proof I provided is the basic idea i had to solve the problem, however i am really not sure of whether it is true or not.
